# Print a certain line in linux or options for nslookup

Tags: linux, bash

I'm very new to linux and bash. I'm trying to find a domain name for an ip address. When I use nslookup I have a bunch of lines like this

```
nslookup 204.228.150.3
```

Output

```
Server: 198.60.22.2
Address: 198.60.22.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
3.150.228.204.in-addr.arpa name = www.computerhope.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
150.228.204.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns.xmission.com.
150.228.204.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns1.xmission.com.
150.228.204.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns2.xmission.com.
ns.xmission.com Internet address = 166.70.254.2
ns1.xmission.com Internet address = 204.228.159.2
ns2.xmission.com Internet address = 207.135.133.2
```

I only want to print www.computerhope.com in the second line. How do I do this? 
Also I tried to use host command as well. It looks cleaner.

```
206.153.126.75.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer www.cyberciti.biz.
```

How do I only print www.cyberciti.biz when I use host command ?
PLease help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ host 75.126.153.202 |sed -e 's/.* //'
www.cyberciti.biz.
```

Comment: Thanks ! but do you mind explain how it works. I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: sed regex: delete all characters to the last space character.

Answer (score 1):

```
nslookup 204.228.150.3 | \
  grep "in-addr.arpa" | \
  cut -d '=' -f 2 | \
  tr -d '[:blank:]'
```

With grep you find the line containing the address. With the cut command you split the line by the "=" sign. With tr you remove any remaining spaces.
The command does not have any error handling in case the address is unknown.

If you would provide more information on what you want to achieve maybe other solutions would come up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to pipe the `host` command to `awk`:

`$ host 75.126.153.202 | awk '{print $NF}'`

`NF` is a built-in `awk` variable which prints the last column of the output of the `host` command, which in this case is the domain name.

You can also pipe `nslookup` to `awk`:

`$ nslookup 75.126.153.202 | awk '$2 ~ /^name$/{print $NF}'`

`awk` returns the last column of the line containing the `name` in its 2nd column.

Comment: I have actually tried this before asking but for some reason it didn't print the last line

Comment: Can you post what it does print?